# Functors that preserve the subset relation on constructs

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, category-theory, definition

> Is there a name for functors between concrete categories over **Set**
>   that preserve '$\subset$'?

Example, for a functor $F:\mathbf {Top}\to \mathbf {Grp}$,
if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then $F(Y)$ is a subgroup of $F(X)$, truly just not isomorphic to a subgroup.

---

Factual functors as $\mathcal P(\cdot)$ and $(\cdot)^I$, $\mathbf {Set}\to\mathbf {Set}$, factually preserve subsets.

My interest of this comes from my striving to create general classes of concrete categories over $\mathbf {Set}$ (considering such different structures as groups and topological spaces to be comparable). However, I want to restrict to structures in which very natural functions, as inclusions and Cartesian projections, are forced to be morphisms.

> Perhaps is it (under certain circumstances) possible to define 
>   canonical injections, not being factual inclusions but perhaps
>   significantly more than just monomorphisms or coretractions?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to define a sensible notion of subset on categories over **Set**, because all notions you can define are typically only up to isomorphism. Or asking the other way around: Why is it important to you that it is not just isomorphic to a subset?

Comment: @Thorsten: Yes, subsets are awkward in abstract category theory, but do exists as such for constructs. I'm interested in classifying functors $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Rel}$ without having to re-invent a lot of things.